# Error with rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

```
yahya@pc ~/RubymineProjects/depot $ rails server
/home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:268: warning: circular argument reference - now
/home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-2.15.7/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:18:in `instance': Please require this file from within a Capistrano recipe (LoadError)
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano/helpers/base.rb:16:in `rvm_with_capistrano'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano/helpers/_cset.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano/base.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano/selector.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano/selector.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano.rb:3:in `require'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:92:in `require'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:92:in `rescue in block in require'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `each'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `require'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
        from /home/yahya/RubymineProjects/depot/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
        from /home/yahya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

It used to work but all of sudden, I got this.

Answer (score 0):

> It used to work but all of sudden, I got this.

That's unlikely.

Apparently, you've updated your version of Ruby since the last time you ran your Rails application. The solution is to revert Ruby to whatever version you used when you built your Rails app, or to bring both Rails and Ruby to a current and mutually compatible version.